# swift - AWS S3 uploading image and then crashing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift3

I'm using the following code to upload data (image) so amazon s3

```
  func uploadData(data: Data, fileExtension: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ filename: String, _ url: String) -> ()) {

        if let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {

        let userId = 1

        let fileName = "\(userId)_\(self.randomString()).\(fileExtension)"

        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(documentsDirectoryPath)/\(fileName)")
        let networkURLString = "\(appDel.assetAddress)/\(fileName)"


        do {

            try data.write(to: url as URL, options: .atomic)

        } catch {

            print("S3 Upload Error")
            completion(false, "", "")

        }

        let uploadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest.bucket = appDel.S3BucketName
        uploadRequest.key =  fileName
        uploadRequest.body = url as URL!

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        let task = transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest)

        task?.continue({ (task) -> Any? in

            let success = (task.error == nil) && (task.result != nil)

            if(!success){
                print("S3 Upload Error: \(task.error)")
                completion(false, "", "")
            } else {
                completion(success, fileName, networkURLString)
            }

            return nil
        })
    } else {
        completion(false, "", "")
    }
}
```

The image gets uploaded successfully; however, after returning completion of success with the filename and the url string... at around the line where it returns nil, the app takes a long time in the background doing AWS cleanup and all of a sudden gives an exception.

I'm trying to push a controller to the navigation bar on completion and it goes through that code but does nothing... as it's doing things in the background... although the image was already uploaded.

Nothing descriptive when it crashes that could help us find the issue.. any ideas?

Edit: Stack trace

```
2017-02-09 15:37:06.453327 HighThere[2021:526754] *** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-491.4/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1577
2017-02-09 15:37:06.462391 HighThere[2021:526754] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18d7e91b8 0x18c22055c 0x18d7e908c 0x18e2a1098 0x1935c33d4 0x1935c30b8 0x1935f2b90 0x1935f5ea8 0x19361a3a8 0x193619ab4 0x19374c8b8 0x19374c79c 0x1000e54d0 0x1000e0a98 0x1000e1390 0x1000e001c 0x1000e00f0 0x19369e924 0x1936b64b4 0x19383e5b4 0x193756e74 0x193756adc 0x193756a40 0x19369ba80 0x190b499d8 0x190b3e4cc 0x190b3e38c 0x190abb3e0 0x190ae2a68 0x190ae2f34 0x18c87bfbc 0x18c87bce4 0x18c87b378 0x18c87ad8c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Great. I just needed to push the controller to the navigation controller on the main thread... brilliant. goodbye 2 hours

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcIntro(), animated: true)
                })
```